# TSV files (tab delimited files) and SP-API

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am completing the migration from MWS to SP-API. I have a question to ask before September 30 arrives (MWS feeds deprecation).

At the moment I am successfully uploading feeds (POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA) in bulk with the new SP-API using the same exact format I used in MWS. I am talkig about tsv files (tab delimited file) like this one:

```
sku product-id  product-id-type price   quantity    item-condition  leadtime-to-ship    merchant-shipping-group-name
2AH1-9GHTA17057307  0000000003723   EAN 7,00    0   11  3
```

Few hours ago I started to worry about such files. Will they still work? Maybe this is a silly question but I need to double check it before it's too late.

Thank you for yout time.

Answer (score 0):

This should still work with the new SP API, see [this](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2020-09-04-use-case-guide#:%7E:text=Yes-,Request%20example%3A,-POST%20https%3A//sellingpartnerapi) example in the documentation.
The example has a contentType of `text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8`.